# Comments not rendering MathJax by default in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mathjax

Unlike the web version, the comments section in the Android app doesn't render MathJax by default. Though there is a 'Render MathJax' menu option for comments (need to selected each time), it would be better user experience if shown by default.

Is there a concern on performance stopping default rendering?